# Left Join and keep unique columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need to left join two df(X1 and X2) and keep only unique columns.

The below code works if I have to do normal join:

```
merge(X1,  X2)
```

**Sample Data**:

```
X1<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group1"),
                     "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","B"),
                      "new_col"=c("Aa","Aa","Ba","Ca","Da","Ea","Ba"),
                     "Total"=c(35,26,10,9,5,11,13))

X2<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2"),
                "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D"),
                "new_col_b"=c(351,261,101,91,51),
                "Total_b"=c(35,26,10,9,5))
```

**Sample Ask**:

```
Merge column -> Group.Name
merged dataframe columns -> Group.Name,Sub_group_name,new_col,new_col_b,Total_b
```

The below code is giving me all the repeated columns also:

```
merge(x=X1,y=X2,by=c,all.x=TRUE)
```

**I also can't specify individual column names as I have more than 100 columns in one df.**

I searched but couldn't find any answers. Any help please

Comment: You can check with `semi_join` i.e. `semi_join(X, X2, by = "c")`

Comment: @akrun: In the merged dataframe it is not taking columns in X2... like "e"

Comment: @Ryan: Same problem, column "e" is not coming

Comment: @akrun: Aded sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to do a normal `merge`, then just remove extra columns from `X2` and remove the `.x` from any names.

```
out <- merge(x=X1,y=X2,by='c',all.x=TRUE)

# remove columns from X2
out <- out[!endsWith(names(out), '.y')]
# rename columns from X1
library(magrittr)
names(out)[endsWith(names(out), '.x')] %<>% substr(1, nchar(.) - 2)

out
#   c a b d e
# 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

Data used:

```
X1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 1, d = 1)
X2 <- data.frame(b = 1, c = 1, e = 1)
```

Comment: Ryan, I have many columns in X1 and X2 so, it would be difficult for me to manually remove those columns